# Problem with cob_bringup: Property 'laser_front_roll' not defined in "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/init.py" (line 369)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to launch the robot (`$ roslaunch cob_bringup robot.launch`), however, I get the following error:

```
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/indigo/share/cob_hardware_config/raw3-2/urdf/raw3-2.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1].
```

Also (`$ rosrun xacro xacro.py /opt/ros/indigo/share/cob_hardware_config/raw3-2/urdf/raw3-2.urdf.xacro`
) returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 62, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 696, in main
    eval_self_contained(doc)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 626, in eval_self_contained
    eval_all(doc.documentElement, macros, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 553, in eval_all
    eval_all(body, macros, scoped)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 532, in eval_all
    eval_all(cloned, macros, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 609, in eval_all
    result = eval_text(at[1], symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 483, in eval_text
    results.append(handle_expr(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 470, in handle_expr
    return eval_expr(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 444, in eval_expr
    result = eval_term(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 418, in eval_term
    result = eval_factor(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 398, in eval_factor
    return neg * eval_lit(lex, symbols)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 369, in eval_lit
    raise XacroException("Property wasn't defined: %s" % str(ex))
xacro.XacroException: Property wasn't defined: u'laser_front_roll'
```

Having a look at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/122021/xacro-problem-invalid-param-tag-cannot-load-command-parameter-robot_description/) link wouldn't solve my problem though cuz mine has sth to do with exception about laser_front_roll which doesn't exist.

Can anybody help me out with such problem?
Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226077/cob_bringup-problem:-file-%22/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py%22,-line-369,-in-eval_lit-----raise-xacroexception(%22property-wasn%27t-defined:-%s%22-%-str(ex))-xacro.xacroexception:-property-wasn%27t-defined:-u%27laser_front_roll%27/) by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems as you don't have the correct version of the cob_calibration_data package where laser_front_roll is defined. Are you  using the release version or do you have overlays?

---

Originally posted by [FlorianWeisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25562/florianweisshardt/) with karma: 41 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2016-02-09**:
running ( $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-cob-calibration-data )  returns

```
ros-indigo-cob-calibration-data is already the newest version.
```

It should be a release version, am not sure though cuz it's a lab's pc.

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2016-02-09**:
And this problem popped up when I updated and upgraded ros operating system.

```
   $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

before it was working totally fine.

**Comment by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on 2016-02-11**:
The package version is `0.6.4-0trusty-20160110-105926-0800`, and the parameter files seems to be there.

**Comment by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on 2016-02-11**:
Some packages were held back by the package manager. Now everything seems to be up to date but some transforms are missing.